# How to control code folding in VSCode for a custom language?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, code-folding

We created a VSCode extension to help us work with a propietary language in an application we use. This language is comparable to a complicated Excel cell formulae - basically functions nested within functions. To make the code more readable for ourselves we came up with a formatting style as follows:

```
MyFunction
[
  Section1a
  Section1b
  Section1c
,
  Section2_etc
]
```

Each *Section* can be made up of one or more further nested functions.

We have now found out that styling the code like this breaks the inbuilt code folding. In the above example, if I try to fold the `[ ... ]` section, the following happens:

```
MyFunction
[ ...
,
  Section2_etc
]
```

Having *any* symbol at the same indent level as the `[` causes the folding to stop. Is there any way to force the folding to always match up with it's corresponding bracket? Do we need to implement this in our extension or is there some setting/configuration changes we can make to get it to work?